# Is guava supported the method like xmemcached's [incr] method?

Tags: java, guava

Guava is very useful.

Now, I want to implement a limit for access counter in a period.(e.g. max 3 times in one hours people can do it)

Use Guava's mapMarker or cache is very easy....(like using memcached), but I meet some concurrent problem when increase counter in map.

Could Guava support the incr operation like in memcache? when map's value is integer? or make a new util class for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store a `Semaphore` ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)) instead of a normal integer.  Look at method `tryAcquire()`. For periodically resetting the number of permits, you can use a combination of `drain()` and `release()`. If draining the permit for a brief period is problematic, you could also use `AtomicInteger` and do something like this:

1) Peek the current value with `get()`
2) If there is still quota available, attempt to acquire one quota by performing `compareAndSet(oldValue, oldValue + 1)`.
3) If the value is successfully updated (i.e. true is returned), the thread is allowed to proceed. If not, the thread must retry from (1).
4) To reset the number of permits, use `set()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe Guava is currently working on an API for rate-limiting like this.  It probably won't make it into Guava 12, but 13 or 14 seems reasonably likely.

Answer (score 0):

If you have integer values then you probably want to be using the recently released [AtomicLongMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html).